# Ask for amount, ask repeated question based on amount, total them?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to python. I have a question that asks me to:

1. ask for an amount of laps;
2. ask for the time for each individual lap; then
3. print the total time as well as average, slowest and fastest.

Code so far:

```
lapcount = 0

laps=int(input("Completed Laps: "))
numlaps = (lapcount+laps)
for i in range(laps):
    seconds = int(input('Seconds: '))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list to store the seconds of each lap. And then use the python building methods to get `max`, `min` and average.

**Ex:**

```
laps=int(input("Completed Laps: "))
numlaps = []
for i in range(laps):
    numlaps.append(int(input('Seconds: ')))

print(max(numlaps))
print(min(numlaps))
print(sum(numlaps)/laps)
```